# why absolute element is involved in calculating size of overflow parent ？

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, absolute

There are lots of card to be showed and I need to show menu when I hover one of the cards.

I use `position: absolute;` for menu and use `position: relative;` for the card, but why the scrollbar appeared when I hover on the card ？

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      height: 240px;
      width: 200px;
      overflow: auto;
      border: 1px dashed red;
    }
    
    .card {
      height: 120px;
      width: 120px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: none;
      height: 400px;
      width: 200px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: linear-gradient(orange, pink);
    }
    
    .card:hover .menu {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is because you have added height 400px to menu class and the box height is 240 px. Also, you have set overflow:auto to your box class. Can you share what exactly you want here?

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar has nothing to do with your positioning, it is a result of `overflow: auto;` on your `.box` element.

`overflow: auto;` will show a scrolling bar if a child element overflows its parent container where `overflow: auto;` is set.

Seeing as the `.box` parent-element has a fixed size value `height: 240px;` while its child element `.menu` has `height: 400px;`, it will cause a scrollbar to appear because there is an overflow of `160px`.

While @Yong is correct with document flow in his answer with the `position: absolute;` property, seeing as you have fixed `height` and `width` on all your elements, `position: absolute;` doesn't actually do anything **in this exact reproducible example**.

If I understand your problem correctly, a simple solution to your problem if you want to keep the fixed width and height on your `.box` element, you can simply disable the scrollbar by applying `display: none;` to the `.box` pseudo-element `::-webkit-scrollbar`.

(**NOTE**: As of February 28th, 2022 this is still not supported in Firefox).

Read more about browser support at https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar

**Example with no positioning properties & `-::webkit-scrollbar`**

```css
    .box {
      height: 240px;
      width: 200px;
      border: 1px dashed red;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .box::-webkit-scrollbar{
      display: none;
    }
    
    .card {
      height: 120px;
      width: 120px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      /*position: relative;*/
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: none;
      height: 400px;
      width: 200px;
      /*position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;*/
      background: linear-gradient(orange, pink);
    }
    
    .card:hover .menu {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to remove overflow altogether, you can apply `overflow: hidden;` to `.box`.

Keep in mind the fixed height of `400px` on the `.menu` element will not apply as the fixed height of `240px` on the `.box` element will hide the remaining `160px`. I hope this solves your problem, but a little more detail would help!

Answer (score 0):

### absolute

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
> to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed
> relative to the initial containing block. -MDN

`.menu` is positioned **absolute** therefore it is positioned relative to `.card` which is the closes positioned ancestor to it.

### relative

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the
> document, ... -MDN

And because `.card` is positioned **relative** it would still take space and position according to the normal flow of the document. Therefore, it would still be taken into consideration whether the `.box` or its parent would overflow or not.

Answer (score 0):

with set `position: absolute;` for `.menu` and `position: relative;` for `.card` you able to change the position of `.menu` with `top bottom left right` properties relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element( `.card` position  ).
but in your question, the `absolute`  or `relative` position is not the cause of the scrollbar appear . The reason is the `owerflow` property .
the default value for `owerflow` is `visible` that create no owerflowing . And you created the scrollbar by setting it `auto` because the size of `menu` is larger than `card`.

```css
    .box {
      height: 240px;
      width: 200px;
      /* overflow: auto; */
      border: 1px dashed red;
    }
    
    .card {
      height: 120px;
      width: 120px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: none;
      height: 400px;
      width: 200px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: linear-gradient(orange, pink);
    }
    
    .card:hover .menu {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="box">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```